# JavaFX textfield not updating with MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, javafx

So i'm able to get sql query to run and update the data in my database but i can't get my textfield to update with the calculation. I figured it would be as easy as selecting the new database amount and injecting it into the textfield but i have a feeling i'm failing to do that correctly. I can load the database table in my application and then get the new result but i'd prefer it to automatically show up.

The controller code below

```
@FXML
private TextField orderBox;
@FXML
private TextField totalBox;

public void calculateOrder(ActionEvent event){

String total = totalBox.getText();
String product = productBox.getText();

String queryUpdate="UPDATE ordertable o JOIN product p ON p.productID = o.productID set o.total = o.amount * p.cost";
 String updateBox="SELECT total FROM ordertable WHERE productID = ?";
try{

    query=c.prepareStatement(queryUpdate);
    update=c.prepareStatement(updateBox);
    update.setString(1, total);
    query.execute();
    update.execute();

    //usetString(2, productID);

       query.close();
       update.close();
        rs.close();

    Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Calculated");

    confirmation.show();

}

 catch(SQLException e){

     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

The FXML class.

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="627.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.OrderController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="331.0" prefWidth="419.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="164.0" layoutY="38.0" text="Order" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="86.0" text="orderID" />
            <Label layoutX="13.0" layoutY="128.0" text="productID" />
            <Label layoutX="3.0" layoutY="167.0" text="CustomerID" />
            <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="233.0" text="Date" />
            <TextField id="orderIDBox" fx:id="orderBox" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" promptText="Enter OrderID" />
            <TextField fx:id="productBox" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="customerBox" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="dateBox" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="229.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
          <TextField id="totalBox" fx:id="totalBox" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="330.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
          <TableView fx:id="orderUser" layoutX="164.0" layoutY="74.0" onMouseClicked="#showOnClick" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="447.0">
          <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="columnOrder" prefWidth="75.0" text="orderID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="columnProduct" prefWidth="75.0" text="productID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnCustomer" prefWidth="75.0" text="customerID" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnDate" prefWidth="75.0" text="Date" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnAmount" prefWidth="62.0" text="Amount" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnTotal" prefWidth="75.0" text="total" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
            <Button id="loadButton" layoutX="518.0" layoutY="43.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadDataFromDatabase" text="Load" />
            <Button id="editButton" fx:id="editButton" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="293.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#updateOrder" text="Edit" />
            <Button id="deleteButton" fx:id="deleteButton" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="293.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteOrder" text="Delete" />
            <Button id="calculateButton" fx:id="calculateButton" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="330.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#calculateOrder" text="Calculate" />
           <Label layoutX="19.0" layoutY="200.0" text="Amount" />
            <TextField fx:id="amountBox" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="196.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="90.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Button fx:id="addButton" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#AddOrder" text="Add" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see (since I don´t see all the code) You´re just executing the query. You´re not assigning it the result to nothing. 
Your update will work fine and your query too, but since you´re not assigning it to nothing you will not see changes.

Try to assign the query result to your textfield (I don´t know which is the textfield since you don´t say which one you want to update, I guess is total.) and then you´ll be able to see the update in your textfield

Comment: Sorry for that but yes it is total, so far i've had no luck trying to assign it.

Comment: You should be able to have the information if you do something like this:

int total=0;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(updateBox);

while (rs.next()) {
 total = rs.getint("total"); 
}

Comment: so...what did you do?